# Why does only NSLog warn me about using the %lu string format specifier for NSUInteger?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, 64-bit, string-formatting, llvm

For some reason, I get a compilation error when I try to do the following:

```
NSLog(@"row: %lu", indexPath.row);
```

where `row` is of type `NSUInteger`. The error I get is

> Conversion specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')

I can do the following with no compilation errors:

```
NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row: %lu", indexPath.row];
```

I'm using the exact same format string and substitution argument in both cases, but why does `NSLog` freak out while `-stringWithFormat:` seems to be perfectly content? My compiler is LLVM 1.6.

Comment: Maybe the difference is that `NSLog()` is a straight C-style function call, while `-stringWithFormat:` is an Objective-C method call; so the compiler might need different mechanisms for warning about mismatches between format string and actual arg types.

Comment: The Cocoa APIs must be doing some sort of automatic type conversion, which is why I've gotten away with this for so long I imagine!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All devices that iOS currently runs on are 32-bit. If you want to silence the warning:

```
NSLog(@"row: %lu", (unsigned long)indexPath.row);
```

[Edit: As of the iPhone 5s, it is no longer true that iOS is always 32-bit.]

Comment: ? Really? I must be crazy. I could have sworn that iOS was 64-bit... I'm extremely embarrassed now. I guess I should just hang up the towel if I don't even know the architecture of the devices I'm developing on... Nevertheless, that still doesn't answer my question about `-stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: I admit that I don't know why it doesn't throw the warning there. It could just be a Clang 1.6 issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The easiest way to tell would be to print `sizeof(int *)`. If it says 4, it's 32-bit. If it says 8, it's 64-bit. AFAIK, all iOS hardware is 32-bit; you might be thinking of running the Simulator in 64-bit x86, or maybe the fact that the iOS APIs that also exist on Mac OS X are a subset of those that exist in 64-bit on Mac OS X.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: I think my confusion came exactly from the fact that the common APIs exist in 64-bit form in Mac OS X. Anyway, stupidity aside, I still am very curious why only `NSLog` seems to complain about this issue.

Comment: @LucasTizma: It's because you use -Wformat (as you should). With that, Clang will warn when you pass an argument whose type doesn't match the format specifier that consumes it. This is a feature, particularly in variadic arguments, where there's no type safety. In assignments and non-variadic arguments, implicit casts usually do the right thing with no need for a warning.

Comment: @PeterHosey: I can't manage to get `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` to give any warnings; see [LLVM bug 10275](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10275). According to 10274, it's a surprise that format checks work for NSLog.

Comment: @tc.: With Xcode 4.3.1's Clang, it does indeed work for `NSLog` but not `stringWithFormat:`, even though both are declared with the relevant attribute. Weird.

Comment: I added an answer with the alternative of using `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64`, which has the advantage of not requiring any code changes.

Comment: I just do `%ju` and cast to `uintmax_t`. When `NSUInteger` goes 128-bit in a century, I'm ready for it.

Comment: iOS 7 and the iPhone 5S (and presumably the next iPad) are 64-bit, so the time to think about this has definitely arrived.

Answer (score 7):

I've run into this same issue, and although @Wevah is correct and his answer works just fine, there's another option that doesn't require any code changes. See the following Apple documentation for details:

[String Programming Guide | Platform Dependencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW5)

[64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa | Building 32-Bit Like 64-Bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247-CH4-SW2)

The `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` preprocessor macro is quite helpful. You can set it in your Xcode project settings (under `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`) or just put `#define NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64 1` in your precompiled header (.pch) file. In my app, this eliminated 11 warnings without any code changes.

This works because `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are the same size (4 bytes) on iOS, so changing the typedef of `NSUInteger` makes the compiler (and the developer) happy, but the hardware doesn't care, since it's just doing integer math in both cases. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation recommends casting the 64 bit value to a 32 bit value using %lu and %ld.  This poses a problem if you actually use the extra 32 bits.  Format strings %qu and %qd specify a 64 bit value (unsigned and signed respectively).  If you want code that will compile in either mode, then values declared as NSUInteger or NSInteger will have to be cast to a UInt64 or SInt64 in the parameter list to avoid the warning.